# \numexpr with parentheses / order of operations

Tags: arithmetic

I feel very silly. Basically I want to divide the result of an addition with \numexpr, such as:

```
(10 + 5) / 3
```

The problem is that if I put parentheses there, like `\numexpr (10+5)/3 \relax` my online editor gives me back a syntax error. The only way I found so far is doing:

```
\numexpr \numexpr 10+5 \relax / 3 \relax
```

But honestly it's a pain to read. Is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: `\the\numexpr(10 + 5) / 3\relax` prints `5` an no error...

Comment: Please, show more context of the error (minimal example). The `\numexpr (10+5)/3\relax` cannot raise arror.

Comment: It raises an error for some reason in my online latex editor. Anyway the package xfp has what I need. I also found \fpeval after that and it's awesome. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}

\inteval{(10+5)/3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It assumes you're doing integer arithmetic, mainly because your code example uses `\numexpr`. If the result needn't be integer-valued, just omit the `math.floor` part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\inteval[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(math.floor(#1))}}
\begin{document}
\inteval{( 10 + 5 ) / 3 }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution with PSTricks only for fun purposes.

```
\documentclass[border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-calculate}
\begin{document}

\pscalculate{(10+5)/2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you want to get the output in a fractional form, you can use Computer  Algebra System named SageMath that can be invoked from LaTeX via `sagetex`  package as follows. An extra setup is needed, let me know if you need it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}

$\sage{(10+5)/2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]